# How to include a php script in react app

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, reactjs, post

I'm trying to get a working contact form on my website and am following this article's [guide](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form). The guide gives a php script to handle the post, but I'm using a create-react-app and I don't know how to include the `mailer.php` file into the project.

## form

```
   <form id="contact-form" name="c-form" method="post" action="mailer.php">
                                        <div className="input-field">
                                            <input
                                                id="first_name"
                                                type="text"
                                                className="validate"
                                                name="first_name"
                                                required/>
                                            <label for="first_name">Name</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="input-field">
                                            <input id="sub" type="text" className="validate" name="sub"/>
                                            <label for="sub">Subject</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="input-field">
                                            <input id="email" type="email" className="validate" name="email" required/>
                                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="input-field">
                                            <textarea
                                                id="textarea1"
                                                className="materialize-textarea"
                                                name="message"
                                                required></textarea>
                                            <label for="textarea1">Message</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="contact-send">
                                            <button
                                                id="submit"
                                                name="contactSubmit"
                                                type="submit"
                                                value="Submit"
                                                className="btn waves-effect">Send
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

## mailer.php

```
<?php

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "jportorreal77@gmail.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

## reactjs

```
componentDidMount() {

    var $form = $("#contact-form");
    var formData = $form.serialize();

    $form.submit(function (event) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        event.preventDefault();

        // TODO
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            success: function (response) {
                console.dir(response);
            },
            fail: function (err) {
                console.dir(err);
            }
        });

    });

}
```

## problem

whenever I submit the form I get a

`POST http://localhost:3000/mailer.php 404 (Not Found)`

error. How do I get this working.

Comment: Where `url: <local-php-script>` is, include in the relative pathway to where it's located in the codebase.

Comment: the relative path should be `~/mailer.php`, but I don't know how to get the file `mailer.php` included in the project.

Comment: The php should not be included in the project. It could be running on a different server and port. You could use the built-in php server for testing locally: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php.

Comment: https://github.com/DannyGarciaMartin/react-webpack/blob/master/js/source/comp/AccountForm.jsx this resource might show you how to include the mailer.php file. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create-react-app is an amazing piece of software which helps developers start up a **front-end** application with little need for configuration. However, it does not have php with it.

Here is how you can make it work

1. The first thing you have to do is try to ensure you have a php server running. Follow [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p2.html) if you need help in that. Lets say that you managed to get your php page working at http://your-host/mail.php.
2. After having visited   http://your-host/mail.php to ensure its
   working, send the data async

Answer (score 1):

In my case from this problem, there I get status page 404 on local host ( http://localhost:3000/post), I am solved with calling my website address of host domains. And, you can try one of two away:
1. use Wamap, Xamp or something else where have Apache server for PHP, Port = 80. In your package.json of application must add row

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:80"
```

And may be add from Php file some for CROS
2. using system like in Word Press, there existing file function.php, who is like heart. Because in React file can't inserting php code,but php code don't add and from public/index.html. but in this case try make some java script file who can to be connection between react and php.
In any case all code must when you develop you must have run both servers ( react node and apache). On Apache the best away make Virtual Host with all granted. Make one htacces file, like is content

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Special Folder for php, Special Folder for react app. File .htacces must put in php folder.I hope so, can help how I can for now. All the best

Comment: When using React and PHP together, the best way is to create two folders in the project folder. In one application response in another PHP. You can see the code on my profile at the academy site: https://www.academia.edu/37293567/Slanje_podataka_iz_React_apliakcije_preko_php_scripta_u_Json_fail_-Sending_data_from_React_to_php_script_in_Json_fail. The text is written in my Serbian language, but in the code you will all have to say it yourself. But I try to be as short as possible.

Answer (score 1):

When using React and PHP together, the best way is to create two folders in the project folder. In one application response in another PHP. You can see the code on my profile at the academy site: https://www.academia.edu/37293567/Slanje_podataka_iz_React_apliakcije_preko_php_scripta_u_Json_fail_-Sending_data_from_React_to_php_script_in_Json_fail. The text is written in my Serbian language, but in the code you will all have to say it yourself. But I try to be as short as possible.
First beside creating two foders, it is necessary to allow the data unobtrusively to go by using a proxy for the port 80 where PHP works in response to the application in the failed package.json, after setting .htaccess fail in the PHP folder and there to do that on my link of the ademi or overlay it my PHP failed. Of course, you can change the names of the input fields and the other you need. In principle, json is first decoded from the decoded part according to the data usage principle from a plurality of data being transmitted to each data in a row of data obtained from the decoded received subpages from the React application. Because, as is known, server work is performed through methods.

Comment: Please give proper explanation of the answer you are trying to suggest.

Comment: You can download code from my link and see how can use React and PHP together

Comment: You have next organisation in your project React-php: Project folder  have React-app folder Public folder Index.html,  Src folder App.jsIndex.js Package.json and Server folder Test.php  Posts.json ans from my link have and code for this file

Answer (score 0):

You can create APIs from your back-end, and host the back-end as you would normally do with a hosted PHP project, using any server of your choice and use the endpoints in your React Project